# How do I display a barcode, only when it is in the last page

Tags: barcode, hp-exstream

I have a document, in which there is a page, that flows. I don't know till how many pages the table is going to flow. Now, I need a barcode to be displayed in the last page (last flow page). I tried writing the rules, by using 
SYS_Page_PrintedValue = SYS_Page_TotalPrinted, 
also tried SYS_PageInDocument = SYS_PageTotalInDocument 
and then I have tried SYS_Page_PhysicalInDocument = SYS_PageTotalPhysicalInDocument.

But did not work. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By placing the Barcode relative to the bottom of your table, as the table flows it will therefore always be on the last page.

Answer (score 0):

You can place barcode directly on the flow page under the flow frame and set that page as last flow page.

[image: drag document into the edit panel and then right click on the flow page]